# How to convert a series of one value to float only?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a series which has only one value and I want to get that value only. I ran a code to get the value by index matching and I got a series like this:

```
(normal_sum['KWH'][(normal_sum['KWH'].index == date)])

Timestamp
2017-04-02    2934.93
Freq: D, Name: KWH, dtype: float64
```

But when I tried to convert it into a float like this,

```
float(normal_sum['KWH'][(normal_sum['KWH'].index == date)])
```

it is throwing an error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
```

The expected output is simply the number itself, not in any table or array:

```
2934.93
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Also, I am facing another problem:

Suppose I get an empty series. Then how can I convert it to zero?

When I do this,

```
(normal_sum['KWH'][(normal_sum['KWH'].index == date)])
```

I get a series like this:

```
Series([], Freq: D, Name: KWH, dtype: float64)
```

Comment: Now you can use `item()`. See also [my full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76789806/1048186).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `loc`

```
normal_sum.loc[date, 'KWH']
```

---

See @MaxU's answer for `at`

---

Also `get_value`

```
normal_sum.get_value(date, 'KWH')
```

---

To return zero when date isn't in the index, you can

```
normal_sum.KWH.get(date, 0)
```

Comment: Suppose if i get an empty series by matching the index, then how i will be able to return the value as 0.

Comment: @Dheeraj I've added to my post

Answer (score 9):

There is now (as of when?) a dedicated function for this:

```
normal_sum.item()
```

An advantage of the method is that it will raise an exception if there is not exactly one item.

Answer (score 7):

if there is only one element in the data series, you could convert it to list by calling `tolist()` and taking the first element of the new list by referencing `[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

we can use [Series.at[...]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.at.html) method for **scalar** lookup:

```
In [138]: normal_sum = pd.Series([1.234], index=['KWH'])

In [139]: normal_sum
Out[139]:
KWH    1.234
dtype: float64

In [140]: normal_sum.at['KWH']
Out[140]: 1.234
```

Answer (score 1):

As it says, you are trying to convert a Series to a float which is not possible. Potentially a Series could have several entries, and each of this entry doesn't have to be a float or an integer, it could be anything. So you have to select your specific entry, either with (bad way):

```
normal_sum['KWH'].loc[0]
```

or

```
normal_sum['KWH'].iloc[date]
```

Edit: Chain indexing done as previously should be avoided, the following way is better.

If you are select directly form the dataframe (and not from the Series normal_sum['KWH']), you can just do:

```
normal_sum.iloc[0,0]
```

or

```
normal_sum.loc[date, 'KWH']
```

Comment: Chained indexing is not good practice.  Also, `normal_sum.iloc[date, 'KWH']` won't work.

Comment: Just a typo for the iloc, I meant loc. I also added the editing for the chained indexing